# Failure to force a signal with a verified path using uvm_hdl_force?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, uvm, test-bench

I'm trying to force a signal to from within a uvm sequence. I'm using the uvm_hdl_force method.

My syntax, run from within the task in my uvm sequence is:

```
if( !uvm_hdl_force ("ex_top.ent_lvl1.ent_lvl2.signalname",1'b1);
`uvm_fatal("CM_BUSY_SEQ","uvm_hdl_force failure of signalname")
```

I'm finding that this always failing.

I've verified the path and if I run uvm_hdl_check_path("ex_top.ent_lvl1.ent_lvl2.signalname") it returns 1, indicating that the path exists. Given that I'm not sure why  the force is failing or what I else I should be checking?

I am also open to other methods of forcing the signal high if there are better methodologies then what I'm trying.

This is a mixed code design. The top level is verilog and the lower level level modules including the one where the specific signal I'm trying to force is located are VHDL.

Thank you

Comment: Cross language support varies from tool to tool, it is not a standardised thing. Have you checked if your tool supports this?

Comment: This command requires a back-door forcing of signals. Usually in optimized simulation models back-door forcing is turned off because it badly affects simulation performance. It must be specifically allowed for all or for some signals. The way it is done depends on the simulator. It looks like it is turned off for this particular signal in your model.

Answer (score 2):

From provided snippet the solution is following, wrap the fatal to `begin-end`. As the `;` will mean end of line and thus terminates the if clause. Or if you do not want to use `begin-end` do not put `;` after the if clause.

```
    // this ; invokes end of condition, to be safe wrap the fatal to begin end 
    //                                      |
    //                                      V
    if( !uvm_hdl_force ("tb_top.test",1'b1)); 
        `uvm_fatal("CM_BUSY_SEQ","uvm_hdl_force failure of signalname")
    // |
    // |
    // V
    if( !uvm_hdl_force ("tb_top.test",1'b1)) begin
        `uvm_fatal("CM_BUSY_SEQ","uvm_hdl_force failure of signalname")
    end
    // Or without ;
    if( !uvm_hdl_force ("tb_top.test",1'b1))
        `uvm_fatal("CM_BUSY_SEQ","uvm_hdl_force failure of signalname")
```

---

Moreover most tools support their own system-tasks for forcing values:

- Xcelium `$xm_force(string path,string value)`
- Questa  `$signal_force(string path,string value)`

There are possibly more parameters for these tasks, but I recommend to look for them inside the reference manual for your tool.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I have fixed this by moving away from uvm_hdl_force to a traditional force statement